# Node rotation doesn't follow a finger

Tags: ios, rotation, sprite-kit

I'm trying to rotate an arrow to follow a finger movement but it performs weirdly. It is definitely not following it. I'm trying to do it in touchesMoved. I tried to do this:

```
var fingerLocation = CGPoint()

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        fingerLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let currentOrient = arrow.position
        let angle = atan2(currentOrient.y - fingerLocation.y, currentOrient.x - fingerLocation.y)
        let rotateAction = SKAction.rotateToAngle(angle + CGFloat(M_PI*0.5), duration: 0.0)

        arrow.runAction(rotateAction)

    }
}
```

And also tried this:

```
var fingerLocation = CGPoint()

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        fingerLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
}
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
   var radians = atan2(fingerLocation.x, fingerLocation.y)
    arrow.zRotation = -radians
}
```

I also tried SKConstraint.orientToPoint but had no luck in it either. What am I doing wrong? Every answer to similar question is suggestion atan2, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rotate the sprite towards to touch location, it should be simple as :

```
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

    var dx =  hero.position.x - positionInScene.x;
    var dy = hero.position.y - positionInScene.y  ;

    var angle = atan2(dy,dx) + CGFloat(M_PI_2)

    hero.zRotation = angle
```

It worked when I tried, so it can give you an basic idea where to start. Or I misunderstood what you are trying to achieve...

**EDIT:**

Currently what you will get if you try to convert angle to degrees is angle in range from -90 to 270 degrees. Its described [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/69678/60351) why. If you want to work with angle in range of 0 to 360, you can change to code above to:

```
    var dx = missile.position.x - positionInScene.x ;
    var dy = missile.position.y  - positionInScene.y;

    var angleInRadians = atan2(dy,dx) + CGFloat(M_PI_2)

    if(angleInRadians < 0){
        angleInRadians = angleInRadians + 2 * CGFloat(M_PI)
    }

    missile.zRotation = angleInRadians

    var degrees = angleInRadians < 0 ? angleInRadians * 57.29577951 + 360 :  angleInRadians * 57.29577951
```

Here is the result with debugging data:

[image]

Comment: Yep, it's working! I don't know why I experienced troubles with it :-) Thank you!

Comment: @Whirlwind the calculations should be `dx = touchLocation.x - hero.position.x`, `dy = touchLocation.y - hero.position.y`, and `let angle = atan2(dy, dx) - CGFloat(M_PI_2)`

Comment: @Epsilon According to the docs, a positive value assigned to the zRotation property indicates a counterclockwise rotation. This is what can be seen in video I've posted. I am pretty sure that your and mine example have exactly the same effect, but if you don't agree, can you clarify the difference ?

Comment: @Whirlwind if you want to calculate the angle of the touch relative to the missile, you should use `dx = touchLocation.x - missile.position.x ...`. If you want to find the angle of the missile relative to the touch, use `dx = missile.position.x - touchLocation.x ...`. The difference between the answers is 180 degrees. If you offset the latter by 180 degrees, you'll have the correct angle. You accomplish this by adding 90 degrees and the missile's image is already offset by 90 degrees (because missile faces up when `zRotation = 0`).